# plot data points with distance equal to error

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am quite new to R and am trying to replicate an x axis of quality where the data points are scaled with the distance between them. Eg, Qscore of 5 = error rate 32%, Qscore of 7 = error rate 20% etc as below

```
Qscore  Error rate
5   32%
7   20%
10  10%
12  6.30%
15  3.20%
```

I want to plot so that the distance is not equal between the data points, but as the difference between Qscores spatially - ie. the distance between Qscore5 and Qscore7 is far greater than the difference between Q12 and Q15 and I want the graph to represent this spatially.

Is it possible to represent this on the x axis so that if I label the x axis Q5-Q15 the space between Q5 and Q7 labels is larger than the space between the Q12 & Q15 labels etc?

Any pointers to resources would be great - I am using tidyverse and rstatix! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have data like this?

```
data <- tibble(qscore = c(5, 7, 10, 12, 15),
           error_rate = c(0.32, 0.2, 0.1, 0.063, 0.032))
```

To show the distance in error rate for the qscore, you could do something like this:

```
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = error_rate)) +
  geom_label(aes(label = qscore), y = 0.5)
```

That would give you a plot like that:
[image]

Not sure this is what you are looking for but maybe it helps :-)

Comment: Hi, this was actually super helpful thank you! However I would also like to be able to make the ticks on the x axis distributed in line with error value - would you be able to help? - So for example, you would have Q5 and Q7 fairly close together as labels on the left of the x axis and then Q10 further away towards the right with a larger gap between Q7 and Q10 labels etc?

Answer (score 0):

I think OP is asking for something more where the *distance* between the points on the x axis is proportional to the error, so more like

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

data <- tibble(qscore = c(5, 7, 10, 12, 15),
               error_rate = c(0.32, 0.2, 0.1, 0.063, 0.032))

data %<>% mutate(
  cumul_dist = cumsum(error_rate))

# Closer to what OP is asking
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = cumul_dist, y=qscore)) +
  geom_point()
```

which gives

[image: this result]

However (and I emphasise I'm unaware of the purposes OP needs this graph for), I think a better way to represent would be using error bars like this:

```r
# Better representation of data IMO
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = seq(length(qscore)), y=qscore)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=(qscore-0.5*error_rate), ymax=(qscore+0.5*error_rate)), width=.1)
```

which gives

[image: this result].

Hope that's useful!

Edit: to set the x ticks, something like

```r
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = cumul_dist, y=qscore)) +
  geom_label(aes(label = qscore), y = 0.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=data$cumul_dist, 
                   labels=data$qscore)
```

gives [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrJMr.png).

This makes the labels a bit redundant so you could switch back to a geom_point():

```r
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = cumul_dist, y=qscore)) +
  geom_point(y = 0.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=data$cumul_dist, 
                   labels=data$qscore)
```

which gives [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAfbk.png).

Comment: Thank you! So helpful, but I also want to put the labels on the x axis at the intervals in relation to error rate too so that if I labelled the x axis with Q score (Q 5, Q7 etc) the Q5 and Q7 labels further apart than the Q7 and Q10 and the Q10 & Q12 labels will be closet together as there is the least difference between them - can you help with that at all? Thank you!

Comment: Try ```r data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = cumul_dist, y=qscore)) +
  geom_label(aes(label = qscore), y = 0.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=data$cumul_dist, 
                   labels=data$qscore)``` -- The scale_x_continuous specifies the xticks, and I've set the labels as the Q score

Comment: Thank you!!!!! you have really helped me a lot on this and I now have the graph I needed!!

Comment: No problem, glad it's working for you :)